# autocomplete based on option value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have here autocomplete from jquery.com. Instead of making a variable to show in autocomplete. I want to show autocomplete from database records. I want only show in autocomplete the records based on dropdown option value. How to do this? Please help me. I'm stuck in here.

This what I have here right now. But how to do this if the comparing value is from option value?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
```

Here's my autocomplete.php

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo $row['item']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's autocomplete code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="main" name="main">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote. You'll have to create a JSON response for the plugin to understand the values correct. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Read more on the last link to learn how you need to format the data. You'll likely need to use `json_encode`

Comment: @Newbi3 can you help me more? I'm begging you

Comment: You are echoing the values in php with "\n". I believe autocomplete expected a JSON object returned from php.

Comment: @SajithNair That would be a big problem with me :( I don't how to start making JSON

Comment: I have added the PHP changes to my answer

Comment: I'm curious to see what values are in your $_GET global array. And yes  I agree with @SajithNair it does need to be JSON. Look up `json_encode` You'll need to give that function an array to encode and echo the contents with `echo json_encode($myArray)`

Comment: One final edit I did $_GET["selected"] should have the final value if javascript is written as I suggested in my answer

Comment: @Newbi3 I followed all he said but still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML should be

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: 'yourPHPFile.php?'
});
});
function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'yourPHPFile.php?selected='+val
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="main" name="main" onchange="changeAutoCompete(this.value)">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP should be like this.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["term"]);
    $selected = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["selected"]);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' AND selected='$selected' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        $str = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $str[] = $row['item'];
        }
        echo json_encode($str);
    }
?>
```

Comment: how about my query in autocomplete.php?

Comment: You will get $_REQUEST['selected'] with the selected value from the option list. You have to write the query based on that.

Comment: @SajithNair still not working. If $q are working? that query was came from different autocomplete jquery

Comment: @SajithNair :( still not. huhu

Comment: Can you use your javascript console and tell me that requests are going to server when you do an autocomplete request

Comment: Not the errors. The console will show the requests made to the server when you type something in the autocomplete textbox. Are you sure you changed the HTML in the way I have given in the answer?

Comment: @SajithNair yes I changed all what you have gave. But still not working

Comment: @SajithNair I found a typo error changeAutoCompete. I changed it but still not working. In autocomplete what $_GET["term"] gets?

Comment: @SajithNair Are you there?

Comment: Yes tell me @ user3318208

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished with basic HTML.

```
<input list="languages">
<datalist id="languages">
  <option value="Dutch">
  <option value="English">
  <option value="German">
  <option value="Chinese">
  <option value="Swedish">
</datalist>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb9Bv/)

Comment: I can get all records based on option value?

Comment: You want to add it so that it creates options with your desired value's and names with PHP. Then it will autocomplete if the option value is written for a part.